# Slow loading first page - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ninject, mvc-mini-profiler

I used miniprofiler for my page because I think I have big loading time for my first page and some other pages. I am starting with miniprofiler but I think it is very good tool. I have this result:

- `http://localhost:50783/`     192.2  +0.0

  - Getting articles from database     2.2    +186.9
  - Find: Index  866.4  +190.9
  - Render : Index  1839.0  +1058.1

    - Find: _Article    530.0  +2809.0
    - Render partial: _Article  64.3   +3339.2
    - Render partial: _Article  8.2    +3404.2
    - Render partial: _Article  12.5   +3413.0
    - Render partial: _Article  8.7    +3426.2
    - Render partial: _Article  7.9    +3435.4
    - Render partial: _LeftMenu     64.8   +3520.4
    - Render partial: _LogOnPartial     3.3    +3556.3
    - Render partial: _RightMenuTest    2530.1 +3591.2
    - Render partial: _NextMatch    3.5    +4088.7
    - Render partial: _Standings    4.7    +4226.5
    - Render partial: _Footer   21.2   +6137.4

Can anybody help me with reducing that times where is Find? What it means? I know that RightMenuTest has the biggest time and I am trying to reduce it too. I have many my own helpers there and I think that is problem with partial view _RightMenuTest. So I need help with reducing that others times.

Thank you

Edited:

_Article:

```
@model SkMoravanSvitavka.Models.Article
<h3>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "Zobrazit", "Clanek", new { id = Model.ArticleID }, null)</h3>

    <p>@Html.Raw(Html.ArticleImageToSmall(Html.Article(Model.Text))) </p>

@Html.ActionLink("Počet komentářů:" + Model.Comments.Count, "Zobrazit", "Clanek", new { id = Model.ArticleID }, null)
```

Index view for article:

```
@model IEnumerable<SkMoravanSvitavka.Models.Article>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sk Moravan Svitávka - oficiální stránky fotbalového klubu";
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Article", item);
    }
}
```

Index in controller for article:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
            using (profiler.Step("Getting articles from database"))
            {
                var model = repo.GetLatestArticles(5);
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I added some code but I am not sure which there is what you need so hope these helps or if you say which one I can added that one.

Comment: Is it the first use of any EF query in your application? In such case you are facing generation of EF views.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RenderPartial insead of Partial:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Article", item);
}
```

Comment: Why is `RenderPartial` better than `Partial`?

Comment: @jrummell It is faster because the result will be written directly to the Response stream during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do the tests when the project is compiled in Release mode as well. ASP MVC is known to perform extra reflection to find views in Debug mode for more comprehensive debugging capabilities.